# Optical flow with bottom camera on aerial vehicle

Tags: opencv, camera, tracking, odroid, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in obtaining an estimation of the linear velocity of the vehicle using optical flow, so which are the best packages for optical flow using the bottom camera of an aerial vehicle? (the camera is a simple webcam).

Or the best approach is to implement optical flow using OpenCV?

Notice that I am using an Odroid X2 (ARM) on the aerial vehicle, so I am searching for something that wont be too demanding for the processor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209663/optical-flow-with-bottom-camera-on-aerial-vehicle/) by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [Semi-direct Visual Odometry](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo). They run on an Odroid U3 and do not recommend a normal webcam. But you can try it anyway.

---

Originally posted by [ReinierDG](https://answers.ros.org/users/22551/reinierdg/) with karma: 26 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on 2015-05-27**:
That's a really good sugestion thanks! From my search the available options are: AR-Track-Alvar, PTAM or SVO.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-01-24**:
Hi! I'm trying to use the SVO package as well but for writing a position hold algorithm, but I'm not sure where to start. Would you mind directing me as to how I can use the info outputted by SVO? I think it's giving me geometry_msgs/Pose but I'm not sure how to use this information exactly